# How do I groupby a pandas column but still individual values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example if my df is like this

```
Team      Time     App

1         10:00    xxxx

1         12:00    yyyy

1         12:00    zzzz

2         11:00    aaaa
```

To something like this

```
Team            Time         App

1               10:00        xxxx

                12:00        yyyy

                             zzzz

2               11:00        aaaa
```

I've tried multiple ways to do this function and I keep getting repeated values, I even tried using the melt function which didn't really seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a groupby, but assuming you want to [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the successive identical values, use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
out = df.mask(df.eq(df.shift()), '')
```

Output:

```
  Team   Time    App
0    1  10:00   xxxx
1       12:00   yyyy
2               zzzz
3    2  11:00  aaaa7
```

Note that this is fine for displaying the table, but not if you further need to work with the underlying data.